# Elm error: I am looking for one of the following things: "'"

Tags: compiler-errors, elm

I'm getting a compile error:

I am looking for one of the following things:

```
 "'"
 "."
 a pattern
 an equals sign '='
 more letters in this name
 whitespace
```

Is it an incomplete type or is the function bad? Capitalized first letter? I have tried building the file block by block and I still get the error as soon as I add the method. If I remove the function type annotation, I get an error on the function definition. I'm clearly misunderstanding a basic concept here

```
module Test exposing (Test, TestRoot, TestId, GetContainedTests)

type  TestId = String

type alias Test =
    { id : TestId
    , containerId : TestId
    , title : String
    , children : List Test
    }    

type alias TestRoot =
    { id : TestId
    , title : String
    , children : List Test
}   

GetContainedTests: Test -> List Test                    -- error here I am looking for one of the following things: "'"     "."     a pattern     an equals sign '='     more letters in this name     whitespace
GetContainedTests item = 
    let
        result : List Test
        result = item.children
            -- if I comment out the GetContainedTests type annotation, I get an error on the ".map" below: I am looking for one of the following things:     an upper case name

        List.map {\childItem -> List.append result GetContainedTests childItem} item.children
    in
        result
```

Note: I'm not asking for help with the function (although I welcome it). I'm trying to get past the compiler error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific error you mention is because you are trying to use a capital letter as the first character of your function `GetContainedTests`. In Elm, all functions must start with a lowercase letter. Only types, type aliases, type constructors, and module names can (must) start with an uppercase letter.

A few other things that you'll get compile errors about:

1. The first argument in `List.map` should be enclosed in parentheses, not curly braces.

You will get a compile error  about defining a recursive type alias. This is because your `Test` alias references itself. For more information on what the problem is, you can [read up on the information in the link provided in the error message](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/0.18.0/hints/recursive-alias.md). The compiler also recommends making `Test` a type rather than an alias, like so:

```elm
type Test
    = Test
        { id : TestId
        , containerId : TestId
        , title : String
        , children : List Test
        }
```

Comment: I want to export (expose) the function. If it does not have a capital letter, does that not violate the protocol?

Comment: You can expose the function the way you've defined up top, given the correct casing: `module Test exposing (Test, TestRoot, TestId, getContainedTests)`. Perhaps you're confusing it with the `Go` language which only exports uppercase names?

Comment: I've been writing a lot of Go lately too and constantly have to do a double take when thinking about what to export